# Is almost everywhere equality preserved under integration?

Tags: lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Suppose we have four Lebesgue measurable functions:
$$
f_1: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad
f_2: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\\
g_1: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \qquad
g_2: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
such that $f_1, f_2$ are almost-everywhere equal by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ and $g_1, g_2$ are almost-everywhere equal by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.

Are the functions
$$
h_1(x, z) = \int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f_1(x, y)g_1(y, z)\ dy
\\
h_2(x, z) = \int_{y \in \mathbb{R}} f_2(x, y)g_2(y, z)\ dy
$$
also almost-everywhere equal by the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes, at least if you assume everything to be integrable. $f_1,f_2$ can also be viewed as functions from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that happen to not depend on $z$; notice that they are equal almost everywhere w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^3$. Similarly for $g_1,g_2$. Then $f_1g_1$ and $f_2g_2$ are functions on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that agree almost everywhere, and we can use Fubini.